# I am unable to find the sum of counts in mysql

Tags: mysql

I need the output as sum of all values of c (i.e. 52)

i used the following query to count the number of distinct fields in the table:

```
mysql> select  count(distinct col1) c from table1 group by date;

+----+
| c  |
+----+
| 51 |
|  1 |
+----+
```

now I need the sum of these count values.

desired output:

```
+----+
|sum |
+----+
| 52 |
+----+
```

I am unable to frame the required query.

Comment: I think you can remove the group by select sum(count(distinct col1)) c from table1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sub select over your count query to get the sum of all counts returned by inner query

```
select sum(c) `sum` from (
  select count(distinct col1) c 
  from table1
  group by date
) t
```